# Создание бота в менюшке телеграм

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

как сделать что бы бот был в меню в Telegram что бы типо открываешь меню в телеграме "☰" и выходить там бот

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: укажите на каком языке пишите и какую библиотеку используете для написания сего бота.
Без этой информации трудно что-то ответить...

Comment: Если имеется ввиду бот как Wallet, то только при сотрудничестве с Телеграм. А так никак такое не сделать